# micropython for STM32F417 controller

Tags: c, makefile, micropython, firmware, stm32f4

I am working on a project where I want to use micropython on an stm32f417 controller , I´ve figured out that micropython doesn´t support my controller , so I should maybe work on the firmware of STM32F407 to let it compatible for my controller and than upload it to the controller. For that reason I am starting to see what I should change in the firmware of "STM32F407",
I get the conclusion that I should change the

```
1: mpconfigboard.h
2: stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h
3: mpconfigboard.mk
```

I could change the two header files (1 , 2) but for the makefile I am confused about what I should change exactly also for the linker file(`LD_FILES = boards/stm32f405.ld boards/common_ifs.ld`) I didn`t get what I should change .

And is there any other file I should change .

This is the change that I made for the mpconfigboard.h :

```
    #define MICROPY_HW_BOARD_NAME "F4"
    #define MICROPY_HW_MCU_NAME "STM32F417"
    
    // HSE is 8MHz
    #define MICROPY_HW_CLK_PLLM (4)
    #define MICROPY_HW_CLK_PLLN (168)
    #define MICROPY_HW_CLK_PLLP (RCC_PLLP_DIV2)
    #define MICROPY_HW_CLK_PLLQ (7)
```

I want to get that project done as soon as possible , any help will be appreciated .
Thank you in advance :)